# Cant get data from IntentService(android, notification)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sorry for my english. I spend meny timis for fix this bug but i cant do this, i dont know why i cant get data which get from server. I have `extends IntentService` class, they pase data for push. 
I parse lke this:

```
  @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        String login = data.getString("login"); //null
}
```

if i use `extends FirebaseMessagingService` everething fine. I get data, i parse like this:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String login = remoteMessage.getData().get("login");
}
```

But i cant use `FirebaseMessagingService` becouse when i close app, Firebase create own notification whitout my data. My qestion: how parse date when extends from `IntentService` ?

server send to firebase json like this:

```
{
"to":"/topics/news",
"notification":{
"title":"test",
"body":"Test",
"icon":"icon_notf"
},
"data":{
"login":"test"
},
"priority":10
}
```

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/ simply follow this link.

Comment: @prakash thanks for link. But when i extends from `FirebaseMessagingService ` and my application is closed firebase create own notification. They dont care which icon or sound i set in my class which create notification.

Comment: Extending IntentService is not the solution. Solution is much easier, see my answer in linked question ^